# Erro de callback: Plugin gerando uma incompatibilidade

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin, plugin-wordpress

Fala pessoal estou fazendo um site em wordpress e estou utilizando 2 plugins da empresa: Optimizepress e Timeline Express, o problema é que o Timeline Express está gerando um erro de callback e que imprime um erro na página em questão.

O erro: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, second array member is not a valid method in /home/comovendersoftware/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

O site: http://comovendersoftware.com.br/

Código do erro

```
do {
        $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] = $priority = current( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );

        foreach ( $this->callbacks[ $priority ] as $the_ ) {
            if ( ! $this->doing_action ) {
                $args[0] = $value;
            }

            // Avoid the array_slice if possible.
            if ( $the_['accepted_args'] == 0 ) {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array() );
            } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
            } else {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] ) );
            }
        }
    } while ( false !== next( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] ) );
```

Sendo a linha 286 do erro:

```
$value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
```

Acabei não achando muitas respostas pra isso, além de que esse erro não está atrapalhando nada no design ou usabilidade do site, tentei usar os WP Debugs como false pra não imprimir, mas também não rolou.

Answer (score -3):

O erro pode estar relacionado a versão do plugin/PHP ultilizada, para esconder (não recomendado) e evitar bug gerados por falhas internas você pode usar o seguinte comando dentro do config.php (na raiz do projeto):

```
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '0');
error_reporting(0);
```